# why nslookup return a private ip address first

Tags: nslookup

why below nslookup return 10.172.0.1 , what does that mean?

nslookup -type=mx www.google.com
**Server:       10.172.0.1
Address:    10.172.0.1#53**

Non-authoritative answer:
*** Can't find www.google.com: No answer

Authoritative answers can be found from:
google.com
    origin = ns1.google.com

Answer (score 2):

That is the IP address if the DNS server you are querying.  This is usually an internal DNS server such as your router, or your ISP's DNS server.

You can specify an explicit server to query by specifying it after the host name.  For example:

```
nslookup -type=mx www.google.com 8.8.8.8
```

Note that sub-domains don't typically have MX records.  If you want to find the mail servers for google addresses you will want to query against just `google.com`

```
nslookup -type=mx google.com
```